# Kafka streams to be used as a database, key value

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

So we have a use case where we need to copy over 1000's of kafka messages twice a day and update a DB.

I was looking at using Kafka streams, and wondering if it would be better to use compacted topic, and then use streams to query the topic? Is that possible. OR would it be better to save the data in a DB and update every day.

any suggestions?

Comment: Something to keep in mind when using Kafka Streams is that your previously *stateless* services become very much stateful. Kafka Streams transforms your services into a distributed database in which kafka is somehow the re-do log. You have to be deeply aware of the myriad of failure modes and ensure that services respond gracefully when one of the stateful services goes down. You also need to monitor the storage of each service as it's a database. I would say keep what you are doing until, sounds a lot simpler.

Comment: Have you tried using Kafka Streams? What's your doubt? What issue are you running into?

Comment: @OneCricketeer No i have not used streams, i was thinking of using it, and whether it suits what i want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Thousands of messages isn't very much. But if every value doesn't really change all that much, you're better off using change-data capture techniques rather than doing scheduled bulk loads.

Kafka Streams can work, but so could Kafka Connect and whatever system you're currently reading from (assuming not files)

Comment: I guess I should have said millions... Currently we being given data via a topic.. and have to update regularly ... so we get the whole set of data even if it hasnt changed

Comment: Bulk loading Kafka topics is fine, but not really its designed purpose. For example, how would you distinguish between two separate loads other than some time gap, or other unique ID? Do you not have a way to send singular events when only those entries change?

Comment: There is a key so we can compact. I was thinking more change data capture and sending events based on that. But thats might not be possible at the moment.

Comment: Right, that is what I'd said in my answer; only send the updated key-values entries that have changed and skip any that haven't. Then compact the updates down into a KTable, to get the latest values for all keys